# Eloquent query builder search not specific to role

Tags: laravel

I have a want to write a query where i get a user with a certain role fulfills search requirements.  Here is my user model

User.php

```
public static function agent_search($query)
{
    return empty($query) ? static::query()
        : static::where(function($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('role', 'agent');
        })
            ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('phone_number', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
}
```

Then I am calling it in my controller like this

```
 User::agent_search($this->search)->paginate(20),
```

The result is calling all the users instead of users with that specific role. How can i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not understanding how your query is being translated into SQL. The query in your question translates to:

```
select * from `users`
where (`role` = ?) or 
`first_name` like ? or 
`last_name` like ? or 
`phone_number` like ? or
`email` like ?"
```

You actually want the following:

```
select * from `users`
where `role` = ? and
( 
`first_name` like ? or 
`last_name` like ? or 
`phone_number` like ? or
`email` like ?"
)
```

To do this you need to change how you are grouping your conditional logic like so:

```
public static function agent_search($query)
{
    return empty($query) ? static::query()
        : static::where('role', 'agent')
                ->where(function($q) use ($query) {
                    $q->where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                    ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                    ->orWhere('phone_number', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                    ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
                 });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use local scope :

```
public static function scopeAgentSearch($query,$search)
{
    if($search) {
        $query->where('role', 'agent')
            ->where(function($sub_q) use ($search) {
                $sub_q->where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('phone_number', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
             });
   }

}
```

in controller :

```
 User::AgentSearch($this->search)->paginate(20);
```